# walk the annotation_custom function inside a walk

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use a `walk` function inside another function. I have a table on the right side of my plot, and I want it to change according to the Site ID variable's value.

Below is an example of what I want the table to look like by using `mytable` as a placeholder.  However, for my actual use case, I want the values to vary by `Site_ID`:

- `Site_ID` = "**H1**": `Alpha1` should be **0.008**, `n_ho` should be **1.09**, and `A` should be **5.45**;
- `Site_ID` = "**H2**": `Alpha1` should be **0.125**, `n_ho` should be **2.28**, and `A` should be **2.78**.
- etc.

My data:

```
> dput(Infil_Data2)
structure(list(
  Time = c(0L, 30L, 60L, 90L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 
           210L, 240L, 270L, 300L, 0L, 30L, 60L, 90L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 
           210L, 240L, 270L, 300L, 0L, 30L, 60L, 90L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 
           210L, 240L, 270L, 300L), 
  Site_ID = c("H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", 
              "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", 
              "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", 
              "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3"), 
  Vol_mL = c(63, 62, 
             60, 59, 58, 56, 54, 52.5, 50, 48.5, 46.5, 82, 77, 73, 68, 65, 
             51, 56, 52, 47.5, 42.5, 37.5, 69, 67, 65, 63, 61, 60, 58, 56, 
             54, 51.5, 49), 
  Soil_Type = c("Clay", "Clay", "Clay", "Clay", 
                "Clay", "Clay", "Clay", "Clay", "Clay", "Clay", "Clay", "Loamy Sand", 
                "Loamy Sand", "Loamy Sand", "Loamy Sand", "Loamy Sand", "Loamy Sand", 
                "Loamy Sand", "Loamy Sand", "Loamy Sand", "Loamy Sand", "Loamy Sand", 
                "Sandy Loam", "Sandy Loam", "Sandy Loam", "Sandy Loam", "Sandy Loam", 
                "Sandy Loam", "Sandy Loam", "Sandy Loam", "Sandy Loam", "Sandy Loam", 
                "Sandy Loam"), 
  Radius = c(1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 
             1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 
             2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 
             1.6, 1.6, 1.6), 
  Suction = c("X.0.5", "X.0.5", "X.0.5", "X.0.5", 
              "X.0.5", "X.0.5", "X.0.5", "X.0.5", "X.0.5", "X.0.5", "X.0.5", 
              "X.1", "X.1", "X.1", "X.1", "X.1", "X.1", "X.1", "X.1", "X.1", 
              "X.1", "X.1", "X.2", "X.2", "X.2", "X.2", "X.2", "X.2", "X.2", 
              "X.2", "X.2", "X.2", "X.2"), 
  Sqrt_Time.x = c(0, 5.477225575, 
                  7.745966692, 9.486832981, 10.95445115, 12.24744871, 13.41640786, 
                  14.49137675, 15.49193338, 16.43167673, 17.32050808, 0, 5.477225575, 
                  7.745966692, 9.486832981, 10.95445115, 12.24744871, 13.41640786, 
                  14.49137675, 15.49193338, 16.43167673, 17.32050808, 0, 5.477225575, 
                  7.745966692, 9.486832981, 10.95445115, 12.24744871, 13.41640786, 
                  14.49137675, 15.49193338, 16.43167673, 17.32050808), 
  Cal_Vol_cm = c(0, 
                 0.124339799, 0.373019398, 0.497359197, 0.621698996, 0.870378595, 
                 1.119058194, 1.305567893, 1.616417391, 1.80292709, 2.051606688, 
                 0, 0.621698996, 1.119058194, 1.74075719, 2.113776588, 3.854533778, 
                 3.232834782, 3.730193979, 4.289723076, 4.911422072, 5.533121068, 
                 0, 0.248679599, 0.497359197, 0.746038796, 0.994718394, 1.119058194, 
                 1.367737792, 1.616417391, 1.865096989, 2.175946488, 2.486795986), 
  X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA), 
  X.1 = c(3.141592654, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
  Alpha1 = c("0.008", 
             "0.008", "0.008", "0.008", "0.008", "0.008", "0.008", "0.008", 
             "0.008", "0.008", "0.008", "0.124", "0.124", "0.124", "0.124", 
             "0.124", "0.124", "0.124", "0.124", "0.124", "0.124", "0.124", 
             "0.075", "0.075", "0.075", "0.075", "0.075", "0.075", "0.075", 
             "0.075", "0.075", "0.075", "0.075"), 
  n_ho = c("1.09", "1.09", 
           "1.09", "1.09", "1.09", "1.09", "1.09", "1.09", "1.09", "1.09", 
           "1.09", "2.28", "2.28", "2.28", "2.28", "2.28", "2.28", "2.28", 
           "2.28", "2.28", "2.28", "2.28", "1.89", "1.89", "1.89", "1.89", 
           "1.89", "1.89", "1.89", "1.89", "1.89", "1.89", "1.89"), 
  A = c(5.452375501, 
        5.452375501, 5.452375501, 5.452375501, 5.452375501, 5.452375501, 
        5.452375501, 5.452375501, 5.452375501, 5.452375501, 5.452375501, 
        2.786831249, 2.786831249, 2.786831249, 2.786831249, 2.786831249, 
        2.786831249, 2.786831249, 2.786831249, 2.786831249, 2.786831249, 
        2.786831249, 5.332170741, 5.332170741, 5.332170741, 5.332170741, 
        5.332170741, 5.332170741, 5.332170741, 5.332170741, 5.332170741, 
        5.332170741, 5.332170741)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -33L), class = "data.frame")
```

My code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
library(gridExtra)

mytable <- cbind(c("Alpha1", "n_ho", "A"), c(1, 2, 3))

plot_2 <- 
  Infil_Data2 %>% 
  split(.$Site_ID) %>% 
  map2(names(.), ~ggplot(.x, aes(Sqrt_Time.x, Cal_Vol_cm)) + 
       geom_point() +
       labs(title = paste(.y)) +
       theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
       stat_smooth(mapping = aes(x = Sqrt_Time.x, y = Cal_Vol_cm), 
                   method = "lm", se = FALSE, 
                   formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE), color = "red") +
       theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 5, 1, 1), "cm")) +
       stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")),
                    label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc = 0.90, #set the position of the eq
                    formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE), parse = TRUE, rr.digits = 3) +
       annotation_custom(tableGrob(mytable, rows = NULL), 
                         xmin = unit(20,"npc"), xmax = unit(25,"npc"),
                         ymin = 0.05, ymax = 0.1))


pdf("allplots_2.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
walk(plot_2, print)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
plot_2 <- 
  Infil_Data2 %>% 
  split(.$Site_ID) %>% 
  map2(names(.), ~ggplot(.x, aes(Sqrt_Time.x, Cal_Vol_cm)) + 
         geom_point() +
         labs(title = paste(.y)) +
         theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 5, 1, 1), "cm")) +
         annotation_custom(tableGrob(cbind(c("Alpha1", "n_ho", "A"), 
                                           c(.x$Alpha1[1],
                                             .x$n_ho[1],
                                             .x$A[1])), 
                                     rows = NULL), 
                           xmin = unit(20, "npc"), xmax = unit(25, "npc"),
                           ymin = 0.05, ymax = 0.1))
```

(I've excluded some of the code for geom layers / other aspects of the plot's appearance, as I do not think they are central to the question asked.)

[image: plot]

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.  Sorry for the late response, my WIFI is limited where I am located.  Thank you for your help.  Could you please explain the [1] and what that is doing?

Comment: @zach If you examine `Infil_Data2 %>% split(.$Site_ID)` (i.e. the list of data frames passed to `map2`, each dataframe has `Alpha1`, `n_ho`, etc. as columns, and their values do not change within each data frame. We simply want one of each, so `.x$Alpha1[1]` etc read the values of the first row.